# C# VLC COM Player Hide Controls

Tags: c#, com, vlc

I am using the VLC `AxVLCPlugin2` type to play movies inside my WinForms applications. Works easy enough, I just want to be able to play and stop individual movie files.

However, I want the user to not really know there's a player there. Ideally it would be totally chromeless and not react to hover or clicks.

Is there a way to hide all the UI stuff that player includes?

[image]

Comment: Try adding `-I dummy` to the `options` string when you `addTarget()`. You should pass that as a parameter when you first instantiate the class.

Comment: I don't believe I call addTarget anywhere?

Comment: Is there an option to pass arguments when you first instantiate the class? You should pass something like `string[] args = new string[] { "-I", "dummy" };` I remember using it a long time ago; let me see if I can find out where I learned it.

Comment: Here: http://www.helyar.net/2009/libvlc-media-player-in-c-part-2/ He linked the full project at the bottom. The `-I dummy` parameter hides the interface.

Comment: That seems like a different object altogether than what I get when I add the COM reference to my forms project. I get a `AxVLCPlugin2` that doesn't take any parameters in the ctor.

Comment: There is "Toolbar" property in control properties. The other way is - use this: vlcdotnet.codeplex.com. BTW, does your ActiveX control (on pic above) playing files and is it with latest VLC? Because I made the same but vlc.playlist.play(); does nothing...